# How do I make anaconda skip the installing of a package?

Tags: yum

I'm using preupgrade to upgrade from Fedora 16 to 17, and I keep getting an unpack error when installing the cups package. I really do not need cups and I want anaconda to skip it and continue. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Is cups currently installed?

Answer (score 1):

Try clean the cache before updating:

```
yum clean all
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Simply Use :

```
# yum --exclude=cups* update
```

OR

```
# yum -x 'cups*' -x 'ifotherpackagetoo*' update
```